# parsing from webpage yields 405 Not Allowed

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, open-uri

I've been looking around for solutions before asking this questions but unfortunately none of them yielded good results.
I get a `OpenURI::HTTPError: 405 Not Allowed` when accessing this specific url:

```
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://streeteasy.com"))

#=> OpenURI::HTTPError: 405 Not Allowed
  from /Users/cyrusghazanfar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:358:in `open_http'
```

also tried:

```
$ curl -I http://streeteasy.com
```

which returned:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Not Allowed
Date: Fri, 22 Sep 2017 20:03:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx
X-DZ: 24.193.31.96
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-DZ: 127.0.0.1
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Edge-Control: no-store, bypass-cache
Surrogate-Control: no-store, bypass-cache
```

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that the server needs an `User-Agent` header to work, so in curl it would be like:

```
curl --header "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0" http://streeteasy.com
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That was my hunch. Do you know how to specify user agent with nokogiri?

Comment: not really, but it should be like adding a normal header, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205221/python-mechanize-how-to-add-a-header-on-a-single-open-call) could help you

Comment: I added a user-agent to my request and it worked except the website is blocking me since it thinks i'm a robot